# Regex for all filenames in a text file

Tags: regex, bash, filenames

I have a file with lines like this:

```
fasdfadf fasd.pdf
fasdf.dafs
/a/b/c.dfe
./file.mp3
```

I want the regular expression that will match this:

```
fasd.pdf
fasdf.dafs
c.dfe
file.mp3
```

Speaking concisely, I want to find all filenames in a text file using Bash, so first of all I need a proper regex, but any additional help will be also appreciated.

Comment: `so first of all I need a proper regex` -- What did you try for this?

Comment: I think that the only proper answer here is to "do your own homework" ... but seriously, this is StackOverflow not FreeRegexWriting. Experiment and learn is my motto – https://regexr.com/. And if you get stuck, we are here to help!

Comment: Any string without a null byte or a slash is a valid filename.

Comment: (con't) It could be said that "file.mp3" is the only filename: everything else (including newlines) is the path leading to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have lazy one.

```
([A-z0-9._-]+)[.]\w+/gm
```

Will match "some number of A-z, dot, underscore and dash" characters followed by "a dot" and followed by "some word".

Next time, play with https://regexr.com/ or some similar tool before asking.

Edit:
Shorter version

```
([\w.-]+)[.]\w+/gm
```

Thanks to ctwheels for pointing out the \w shorthand, that lead me to remember numbers in the filename too

Comment: Isn't `\w+\.\w+` much simpler?

Comment: what about "my_awesome.file.pdf" or "my-dashed-file.2017.pdf"?

Comment: regexr.com says that the slash before gm is unescaped, I try to unescape it adding \ before it, but it doesn't detect any words.

Comment: hover your mouse over it, it will say a nice explication. PS: /gm are the options, set in flags in regexr.com

Comment: thank you a lot! i've found same kinds of regex even before asking here, but nothing worked until i realised to turn gm on in flags, not to paste it to the input field.

Comment: @LordNeo, those weren't part of the original request and information given. If you want to shorten your existing code exactly how it is, you can use `/[\w.-]+\.\w+/gm`

Comment: any character except the null byte or slash is allowable in a filename. Word characters are just the most commonly used.